# What is the origin of this quote about God, Flies, and Spiders?

Tags: quote-source

I recently came across this [comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZkUlv1VVnQ&lc=UgznSKbvpHiOZ52AbqF4AaABAg.9W5xiyO8vq89W67DRq9SKW) on a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/rZkUlv1VVnQ):

> Even god has fruit flies, and for god sized fruit flies you need a god sized spider to keep god's kitchen clean

Maybe it's just *deja vu*, but I am almost certain that I've read this quote somewhere before. However, I was unable to find any information by [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=god+size+fly+spider+kitchen+quote). Does anyone know the origin of this quote?

Comment: Searching for exact quotes is a better bet with Google, otherwise it'll give you all sorts of irrelevant things. But [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spider%22+%22fruit+flies%22+%22god%22+%22god%27s+kitchen%22) doesn't give anything either.

Answer (score 5):

I [asked the person](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZkUlv1VVnQ&lc=UgznSKbvpHiOZ52AbqF4AaABAg.9W5xiyO8vq89koJPj33Enw) who posted the YouTube comment if it was a quote from somewhere. Easy solution, really. Their reply:

> @user-iu7do1xw1i Nicely phrased.  Is that original, or are you quoting something?
>
> @petemorris8499  just made it up

So, apparently it's an original sentence, and not quoting anything.

Answer (score 2):

Google seems not to be providing any results. Therefore, I believe the origin of this quotation is unknown.

---

It appears to have entered the public consciousness as a common expression and exists in many different forms, varying slightly depending on who says or writes about it. For example, "God has His flies even if he needs bigger spiders for them" and "Even God must use spider webs to capture its fruit flies" are two variations.

This phrase may be related to an old proverb popularized by Benjamin Franklin that reads: "For want of a nail, the shoe was lost; for want of a shoe, the horse was lost; and for want of a horse, the rider was lost," exemplifying how small lapses can cause large consequences—a message echoed by imagery present when comparing god-sized fruitflies with god-sized spiders necessary to trap them.